# How do I show a non-geometric and non-arithmetic series converges?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

In my introduction to calculus book, I am given the following question:

"Show that the series

[image]

Is convergent, and find its sum to 8 terms."

The series isn't geometric (no common ratio) and it isn't arithmetic (no common difference). I've managed to provide the following characterization of the series:

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

But from here I've blanked. Perhaps it is something simple I have forgotten -- I'm sure it is in fact -- but I'm not sure how to show this series is convergent (doesn't sum to infinity), nor how to find the partial sum of a non-geometric, non-arithmetic series. The book is an introductory calculus book, and therefore the problem musn't require any fancy maths from Calculus 3 or anything.

Comment: See the [Leibniz Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Comment: To find the partial sum, just do basic addition of fractions: $$1-\frac12+\frac13-\cdots-\frac18=\frac{533}{840}.$$ Or maybe use a calculator. I don't think there's a nice general formula for the $n$th partial sum.